# How to stop loop after user "input" 4 digits in a row

Tags: python, loops

Good afternoon! I wanted to ask how to make it so that if the user enters text into "input" and there are 4 numbers in a row (for example: mmm4213), then the loop ends and "print" is displayed about this eventю

```
numbers_row = 4
while True:
    user_sms = input("Enter: ")
    if ? == ?:
        print("4 numbers in a row")
        break
```

Comment: `input` returns after a whole line is entered, i.e. it waits for "enter" to be pressed. There is no way to modify that. To have different input method, you should use low level functions which listen to individual key press events.

Comment: If you need to process input one character at a time then you could consider using the *keyboard* module. However, bear in mind that *keyboard* doesn't play nicely on macOS (and potentially other platforms). You would need run your script as super-user (sudo)

Answer (score 0):

```
   numbers_row = 4
   while True:
    user_sms = input("Enter: ")
    bools = [c.isdigit() for c in user_sms]
    c = 0
    for flag in bools:
        if flag: 
            c +=1
        else: 
            c = 0
        if c == numbers_row:
            print("4 numbers in a row")
            break
```

Output:

```
Enter: mm1234
4 numbers in a row
Enter: 12mm12
```

Comment: what about 12mmm34

Comment: @stark i edited the answer to deal this case